# Replace YouTube URL with player in nodes and comments?

Tags: files

Is there a module or something similar I can use to replace a YouTube URL with the actual video in a node and also in comments?

I've found a few that work for the node, but what about in comments as well?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Googtube](https://www.drupal.org/project/googtube) module for this. It will provide you with an additional input format, which you can use wherever you want.

From the project page:

> Googtube allows users to embed Youtube, Vimeo and Google Videos in a simple way without tags. When users post a url to videos the link is automatically converted to a video witch is actually embed code.